# JPA/Eclipselink sum all columns value using criteria

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, criteria, criteria-api

I'm developing a web app using Spring MVC 4 with EclipseLink 2.5.0 and MySQL 5.6 in Windows 7. I'm using criteria (Criteria Builder and CriteriaQuery) to get the sum of all fields from the database. 
What I want to achieve is the equivalent in native MySQL of this statement.

```
SELECT SUM(che_monto) FROM ssi_cheque WHERE che_fecha BETWEEN '2015-03-01
' AND '2015-03-31';

| sum(che_monto) |
+----------------+
|    54351367.00 |
```

**Note:** che_monto is a Numeric(10,2) field.

The issue I have is that in several tutorials doesn't show how to make this (I think because is simple), showing only how to sum two factors or making complex math operations. Anyways I have generated the following code:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Number> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Number.class);
Root<SsiCheque> fromSsiCheque = query.from(SsiCheque.class);
...
/** Code that works correctly to generate predicate */
...
query.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(ssiCheque.get("che_monto")))
    .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
```

But I have the following compilation error:

**Bound mismatch:** The generic method sum(Expression) of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path). The inferred type Object is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter

What am I missing? Does eclipselink version is affecting?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How does `SsiCheque` entity define `che_monto` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The generic method sum(Expression) of type CriteriaBuilder is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Path). The inferred type Object is not a
>   valid substitute for the bounded parameter

The reason is that the compiler is unable to infer a proper type for the sum expression.
According to JPA specification `javax.persistence.CriteriaBuilder.sum` method is defined as:

```java
 <N extends Number> Expression<N> sum(Expression<N> x);
```

so it's expected to pass `x` as `Number`, `Integer`, `Double`, `BigDecimal`, etc. rather than `Object`. This is why the above error is produced. In other words the compiler is unable to perform an implicit cast from `Object` type represented by `che_moto` parameter to the `Number` type (or its descendant) which is expected by `javax.persistence.CriteriaBuilder.sum` method.

---

Assuming that `che_monto` field is defined as `BigDecimal`, an example solution may look as follows:

```java
query.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(ssiCheque.<BigDecimal>get("che_monto")));
```

If you would like to make use of strongly typed query definitions with the *Metamodel API* then casting is no longer needed:

```java
query.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(ssiCheque.get(_SsiCheque.che_monto)));
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, just a doubt, if I want to use Metamodel API, do I have to write another class and generate the metamodel?

Comment: You are welcome. Just generate the metamodel from the existing entity class.